# How to log when using Command Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Head First Design Patterns say:

> The Command Pattern encapsulates a request as an object, thereby
> letting you parameterize other objects with different requests, queue
> or **log requests**, and support undoable operations.

Later the book said:

> The semantics of some applications require that we log all actions and
> be able to recover after a crash by reinvoking those actions. The
> Command Pattern can support these semantics with the addition of two
> methods: store() and load(). In Java we could use object serialization
> to implement these methods, but the normal caveats for using
> serialization for persistence apply.
>
> How does this work? As we execute commands, we store a history of them
> on disk. When a crash occurs, we reload the command objects and invoke
> their execute() methods in batch and in order.

I am trying to come up with an example code. The code I wrote till now is:

```
class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Command enableCommand = new EnableCommand();
        enableCommand.execute();
    }
}

interface Command {
    void execute();
    void store();
    void load();
}

class EnableCommand implements Command {

    public EnableCommand() {
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        store();
        System.out.println("Execute Command");
    }

    @Override
    public void store() {
        System.out.println("Storing on Disk");

    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

How the `load()` function is supposed to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly. `store` saves the Command instance, `load` recreates the instance from the stored version. The details depend on the format you store the Command instance in.

Comment: The GoF book mentions the same idea on page 236, but it's not clear to me how they expect that `load()` method to be invoked. I can certainly grasp the concept of serializing and deserializing commands; but putting that method in the interface seems to imply a command object would load itself _after_ being instantiated.